# Compile multiple fields into one

Tags: sql, teradata

Looking to determine a way to run a SQL teradata query where I can get the top combinations that make up counts of customer devices by cust_id, acct_num and then the average amount of kilowatts used per that total population of combination.

So customers can have 1 device and I need to list the device and the average kilowatts, I then would want the next highest combination of customer devices and need to list the combination of "In House" and "In garage' on one row and then get the average bytes for the total of that combination population.

Sample of source data:

```
Electric_device Total_Kilowatts CUST_ID ACCT_NUM    DEVICE_TYPE
2                            75         11556632    1   In House
1                            60         11556632    1   In garage
5                            25         11556632    2   Outside
6                          1155         11556632    2   GPS
```

Result set would be out of 1 million customers and look like below:

```
Count_of_Cust_id    Combinations    Average_Kilowatts
         800,000    In House                      75
         100,000    In House, In Garage           68
```

Comment: Electric_device Total_Kilowats CUST_ID ACCT_NUM DEVICE_TYPE
2 75 11556632 1 In House
1 60 11556632 1 In garage
5 25 11556632 2 Outside
6 1155 11556632 2 GPS

Comment: So basically aggregates for all combinations of DEVICE_TYPE, sorted descending by total population?  What SQL engine are you using?  Sounds like a recursive CTE.

Comment: You're going to need to [edit] your question to provide a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as well as to include at least some effort to do this yourself. (The tag is necessary because answers would need that information; there are wide differences in syntax and available functionality between the database servers, and therefore the specific one in use is relevant and important.)

Comment: @KenWhite: he/she did supply the DBMS in the question: "*run a SQL **teradata** query*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The DBMS obviously wasn't made clear enough, as there was an answer posted related to MySQL and my missing it as well. :-) AaronLS apparently felt the need to ask about it in a comment as well.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear enough, although if you can read-:) Ken are you the stackoverflow police-- what is with the push back-- if you do not want to help -- then don't.

Comment: I have figured out a way to get my device type into fields so I can now sum across although I am stuck at this point-- any guidance is always appreciated.

Comment: Electric_device Total_Kilowats CUST_ID ACCT_NUM DEVICE_TYPE_IN_HOUSE DEVICE_TYPE IN_GARAGE DEVICE_TYPE OUTSIDE DEVICE_TYPE GPS
3 10422541 720511594 1 2 1 0 1
2 0 703660564 1 0 2 0 0
2 0 685791170 1 0 2 0 0
2 2165752 313137114 1 2 0 0 3
1 7460934 283010973 1 1 0 0 2
1 895929 872867768 1 1 0 0 1

Comment: I'm not shure if I understood what you want, e.g. this example customer, should it be counted only once with the average of the combined device types (In House, In Garage, Outside, GPS) or do you want one row for each possible combination like (In House), (In House, In Garage), (In Garage), (Outside), ...?

Answer (score 0):

The following query calculates the various values in steps:

1 The Device Types are concatenated for each combination of Cust_ID and Acct_Num

2 The Total_Kilowatts is summed up for each combination of Cust_ID and Acct_Num

3 The data is grouped by Device_Type Combinations and the count of Cust_ID and the Average_Kilowatts is obtained.

```
WITH RECURSIVE device_types (cust_id, acct_num, devices, lvl)
   AS
   (
    SELECT cust_id, acct_num, MIN(device_type), 1
    FROM customers
    GROUP BY cust_id, acct_num, 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cust_id, acct_num, TRIM(device_type) || ', ' || devices, lvl+1
    FROM customers c INNER JOIN device_types dt
    ON c.cust_id = dt.cust_id AND c.acct_num = dt.acct_num AND device_type > devices
   ),
grouped_devices AS  
  (
   SELECT cust_id, acct_num, devices
   FROM device_types
   QUALIFY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cust_id, acct_num ORDER BY lvl DESC) = 1; 
 ),
summed_kilowatts AS
 (
  SELECT cust_id acct_num, sum(total_kilowatts) total_kilowatts
  FROM customers
  GROUP BY cust_id acct_num
 )
SELECT gd.devices Combinations, COUNT(DISTINCT gd.cust_id) Count_of_Cust_id, SUM(sk.total_kilowatts)/COUNT(DISTINCT gd.cust_id) Average_Kilowatts
FROM grouped_devices gd
INNER JOIN summed_kilowatts sk ON gd.cust_id = sk.cust_id AND gd.acct_num = sk.acct_num
GROUP BY gd.devices
ORDER BY gd.devices;
```

**Reference**:

[Concat rows as a single column in Teradata on The Simple Programmer blog](http://thesimpleprogrammer.blogspot.in/2013/02/concat-rows-as-single-column-in-teradata.html)